# Masstransit with RabbitMQ using .net creates 2 Exchanges for given Type

Tags: masstransit

Below is a sample POC developed in ASP.net Core 6.0 API that uses MassTransit and RabbitMQ to simulate a simple publish/subscribe using MassTransit consumer. However when the code is executed it results in creation of 2 Exchanges and 1 Queue in RabbitMQ.

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(msConfig =>
{
    msConfig.AddConsumers(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

    msConfig.UsingRabbitMq((hostcontext, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host("localhost", 5700, "/", h =>
        {

           h.Username("XXXXXXXXXXX");
           h.Password("XXXXXXXXXXX");

        });

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(hostcontext);
    });
});
```

**OrderConsumer.cs**

```
public class OrderConsumer : IConsumer<OrderDetails>
{
    readonly ILogger<OrderConsumer> _logger;
    public OrderConsumer(ILogger<OrderConsumer> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<OrderDetails> context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Message picked by OrderConsumer. OrderId : {OrderId}", context.Message.OrderId);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
    public class OrderDetails
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string OrderName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    readonly IPublishEndpoint _publishEndpoint;

    [HttpPost("PostOrder")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PostOrder(OrderDetails orderDetails)
    {
        await _publishEndpoint.Publish<OrderDetails>(orderDetails);

        return Ok();
    }
```

**Output from Asp.Net**
[image: Output from Asp.Net]

As highlighted 2 Exchanges are created Sample:OrderDetails and Order.

[image]

However, the Sample:OrderDetails is bound to Order (Exchange)

[image]

And the Order (Exchange) routes to "Order" queue.

[image]

[image]

So, the question is regarding the 2 Exchanges that got created where I am not sure if that's per design or its a mistake on the code that led to both getting created and if its per design, why the need for 2 exchange.

Answer (score 7):

I was pondering the same question when I first started playing with MassTransit, and in the end came to understand it as follows:
You are routing two types of messages via MassTransit, events and commands. Events are multicast to potentially multiple consumers, commands to a single consumer. Every consumer has their own input queue to which messages are being routed via exchanges.

For every message type, MassTransit by default creates one fanout exchange based on the message type and one fanout exchange and one queue for every consumer of this message.

This makes absolute sense **for events**, as you are publishing events using the event type (with no idea who or if anyone at all will consume it), so in your case, you publish to the `OrderDetails` exchange. MassTransit has to make sure that all consumers of this event are bound to this exchange. In this case, you have one consumer, `OrderConsumer`. MassTransit by default generates the name of the consumer exchange based on the type name of this consumer, removing the `Consumer` suffix. The actual input queue for this consumer is bound to this exchange.
So you get something like this:

EventTypeExchange => ConsumerExchange => ConsumerQueue

or in your case:

`Sample:OrderDetails` (based on the type `Sample.OrderDetails`) => `Order` (based on the type `OrderConsumer`) => `Order` (again based on the `OrderConsumer` type)

**For commands** this is a bit less obvious, because a command can only ever be consumed by one consumer. In fact you can actually tell MassTransit not to create the exchanges based on the command type. However, what you would then have to do is route commands not based on the command type, but on the command *handler* type, which is really not a good approach as now you would have to know - when sending a command - what the type name of the handler is. This would introduce coupling that you really do not want. Thus, I think it's best to keep the exchanges based on the command type and route to them, based on the command type.

As Chriss (author of MassTransit) mentions in the [MassTransit RabbitMQ deep dive video (YouTube)](https://youtu.be/2cG2qzNgcsA), this setup also allows you to potentially do interesting stuff like siphon off messages to another queue for monitoring/auditing/debugging, just by creating a new queue and binding it to the existing fanout exchange.

All the above is based on me playing with the framework, so it's possible I got some of this wrong, but it does make sense to me at least. RabbitMQ is extremely flexible with its routing options, so Chriss could've chosen a different approach (e. g. Brighter, a "competing" library uses RabbitMQ differently to achieve the same result) but this one has merit as well.
MassTransit also - unlike some other frameworks like NServiceBus or Brighter - doesn't really technically distinguish or care about the semantic difference between these two, e. g. you can just as well send or publish a command just as you can an event.